# How to use mmap in Python

Tags: python, mmap

I have some difficulty in understanding the Python documentation concerning how to
use mmap.
Imagine that I have at least two separate
programs/processes: a.py and b.py.
How can I create a shared memory between
this two with mmap?
In this shared memory I would like
to be able to put everything: lists, object
(classes instances), semaphores etc...

I know that if I have just one program 
multiprocessed, in this case I can use
Managers to shared data.
What about two, or more, different programs?

How can I resize the mapped area so that it can contain some objects? (List, instance, semaphore...). I don't understand this. In C it's easy becasuse with shm_open and mmap
you get pointers...but here?

Comment: Please link to staded documentation, really. (I have some difficulty in understanding the Python document....)

Comment: @r4. http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Comment: If you already know how to do it using `multiprocessing.Manager` then just use that. You can: `from a import some_func` and `from b import another_func` instead of running `a.py`, `b.py` directly.

Comment: If the access to shared information is not that intensive, I like to use [redis](http://redis.io/) for this job. As an added benefit, I can run the code across multiple hosts.

Comment: Thanks to all! I've got it. Maybe that I forgive about mmap.